# meaning of "make-up" (besides to compensate)

Tags: meaning-in-context, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

More accurately I'm asking about **made up**. Can it be used in the same way as **ended up**?

> She **made up** looking wonderful after going to the hairdresser

Now I know it's kinda weird. There are simpler ways to say that phrase. 
I'm asking this because in the subject of *gerunds and infinitives* I'm asked to correct the mistake in the following sentence:

> The hairdresser **made** me *to look* wonderful

Now the easiest way to fix it is "made me *look* wonderful" and case closed. But is "look" by itself an infinitive? I got confused by this and started looking up ways to fix it with "looking/to look". Can it even be done this way?

Comment: Made-up isn't synonymous to ended up. I'm a bit confused by your question because you used "made-up" in the first half, and "made me" in the second half. Make/made  up is an idiom with a lot of meanings (see here http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+up), while make/made without up is not and means something different.

Comment: Also, and I don't know if this answers your question at all, you could say in the second sentence "The hairdresser made me up to look wonderful" (and it would imply that he hairdresser did more than cut your hair, like styling it, applying makeup, or giving you a make over)

Comment: yes, it does. thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they don't mean the same thing.

"Ended up" means "finished the (literal or figurative) journey", and is normally followed by some indication of where or how you finished.

> We got lost, drove in circles for miles, and finally ended up in Cleveland.
>
> I was angry at Sally, but I ended up forgiving her.

"Made up" has a number of meanings.

(a) Fictional (adjective) "His story isn't true: it's all made up."

(b) Invented a fictino (verb) "He made up that story."

(c) Reconciled, as in, after a conflict. "Alice and Bob had a big fight, but then they made up and were friends again."

(d) Made prettier by applying cosmetics, etc. (verb) "Sally made up her face using eye shadow and lipstick. She also made up her hair with braids and hair clips."

(e) Regained lost ground, compensated. "Our company lost money in the first quarter, but we made it up in the second quarter, so now we are back on track."

Whew, this idiom has a lot of meanings! Maybe there are more that I'm not thinking of.

I wonder if the sentence you quote has been garbled somewhere along the line, as women certainly do go to a hairdresser to be "made up". Perhaps, "She was all made up and looking wonderful after going to the hairdresser."

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second question: in English (and similarly in other languages, I guess), different words and phrases require different kinds of object or complement, and unfortunately there's no obvious reason to this: you just have to learn them.

So "want" takes an infinitive with "to", and optionally an object: *I want to go*; *she wanted me to answer*.

"Make" in this sense (='force' or 'cause') takes an infinitive without "to", and necessarily an object: *She made me take it*.

"Like" takes an infinitive with 'to' and an optional object **or** a gerund ('-ing' form): *I like to see the sunset*; *I like listening to the radio*

Answer (score 0):

The phrases "made-up" and "ended-up" are not interchangeable. The phrase "She made up looking wonderful after going to the hairdresser" is not standard English. The phrase "made up" does, however, have another meaning which is invented, created, or contrived. An example of this usage might be "The character Harry Potter is made up," or in the form of a verb as in "I made up a new recipe."

In English, the infinitive form of a verb is always two words, the first one being "to." Thus, "to look" is an infinite while "look" is not.

Comment: it seems like you didn't read any of the above answers?

Comment: True, I answered first.

Answer (score 0):

so from what i gathered:

1.to make-up can mean to prettify. in this case

"The hairdresser made me up (in order to) *to look* wonderful" or "The hairdresser made up the girl to look wonderful" or...or "The hairdresser made up the girl and she ended up looking wonderful"

2. Make, combined with a subject (me, it, this) can exclude the "to" of an infinitive without causing it to cease being an infinitive

"The hairdresser made *me* look wonderful"
"You made this work"